# Enhancing table MYSQL Performance

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with the following scheme :

```
CREATE TABLE `type_interests` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `interest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `notes` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `type_interests`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `interest_id` (`interest_id`,`type_id`),
  ADD KEY `interest_id_2` (`interest_id`);


ALTER TABLE `type_interests`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=31415;

ALTER TABLE `type_interests`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `type_interests_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`interest_id`) REFERENCES `interests` (`id`);
```

And i have only about 30,000 records in the database but all queries which use this table is consuming alot of time, is it a design problem? note that type_id is linked to more than one table.

Comment: Can you show us a query/queries which are taking a long time?  Off the top of my head, perhaps you are not using any indices.

Comment: I think SHOW CREATE TABLE will show the table more elegantly

Comment: i added an index ('type','type_id') and it solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should index your table properly, more information here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

It depends on your server aswell, you can "tune" your MySQL with this script: https://www.howtoforge.com/tuning-mysql-performance-with-mysqltuner

Comment: i added an index ('type','type_id') and it solved the issue

Comment: I`m glad I could help!